# WSO2 ESB as a RabbitMQ produser

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq

I tried to create proxy which will receive soap request and store it to rabbitmq.
Example from documentation works well, but it always stores full message with envelope and body elements.
 How can I store pure xml message without envelope?
I used payload mediator, but got same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are storing, it will store with envelope as it must have a proper message. Even though you try to remove that, it may cause an error if message doesn't have an envelope.

You can try sending binary format (which will attach xml file in to message: Try this with POSTMAN tool) and it will send the xml file separate one. But still its' better not to remove envelope as it may cause errors.